# Bash: Use single quotes inside a variable

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sed, wget

I have the following script (to get my current IP from an external service):

```
#!/bin/bash
####################################################################
# Gets the public IP address of current server
####################################################################

cmd='curl -s'
#cmd='wget -q -O'
#cmd='lynx -dump'

ipservice=checkip.dyndns.org

pipecmd="sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*\$//'"

# Run command
echo $($cmd $ipservice | $pipecmd)
```

But sed command complains:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I have been googling around on how to use single quotes inside a variable without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is split into words `sed`, `-e`, `'s/.*Current`, `IP`, `Address:`, `//'` etc., so the first command in the `sed` program indeed starts with `'`, which is not a valid `sed` command. Use an array and quoting instead:

```
cmd=(curl -s)
pipecmd=(sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//')
"${cmd[@]}" "$ipservice" | "${pipecmd[@]}"
```

Note that `echo "$(command)"` is equivalent to `command`. In general, make sure that you always quote all variables (there are a few exceptions, though).

Comment: Thanks! It executed the command, but for some reason, sed extraction is not working exactly as need (instead of the IP Address only, I'm getting the IP plus the trailing content).

Comment: @yorch: Probably you need to unescape the dollar sign (unless the result text contains a literal dollar).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `eval` to get the shell to interpret the contents of the variable

```
echo $($cmd $ipservice | eval $pipecmd)
```

You may need extra escaping because of the extra evaluation, although in this particular case I think it's okay as is.

Comment: Eval isn't evil. Eval means "treat this string as shell source code to execute". But that's exactly what you're already doing when you're writing a script. Just make sure that you control whatever you eval, as if it were code that you're writing.